# segmentation fault при обработке строки

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

Столкнулся с проблемой segmentation fault при решении задачи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить.
Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_len(char *string){
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]!="\0"){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int is_correct(char *string){
    int i, word_len, words_num, new_word;
    i=word_len=words_num=0;

    while(string[i]!= 0){
       if(string[i]!=38){
           word_len++;
       } else{
           words_num++;
           new_word = 1;
       }

       if(word_len>20 || words_num>30){
           return 0;
       }

       if(new_word){
          word_len = 0;
          new_word = 1;
       }
       i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  char str[631], str_only_letter[631]; //631 = 630(макс количество символов в строке по условию) + 1(символ окончания строки)
  int length,error;


  printf("Введите предложение: ");
  error = scanf("%630s", str); 
  length = get_len(str); 
  if(!is_correct(str)){ //думаю, что проблема где-то в этой функции
     printf("Предложение введено неверно. Работа программы прекращена.");
     return 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Cама задача:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А сформулировать саму задачу? Чтоб решать? :)

Ну, а причина неприятностей — вы сравниваете **символ** с **адресом** *строки* `"\0"`.

```
string[i]!="\0"
```

Естественно, это сравнение всегда истинно, и вы уходите очень далеко за пределы строки `string`...

Comment: А, понял, спасибо :)